# GitHub Actions: "You've used 100% of included services for GitHub Storage (GitHub Actions and Packages)" after deleting all Artifacts

Tags: github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

Does anyone of you know what GitHub actually stores in their GitHub Storage (for Actions and Packages)?

GitHub keeps telling me:

> You've used 100% of included services for GitHub Storage (GitHub Actions and Packages)

[image: GitHub Storage usage]

I deleted all my old workflow runs
I have tried two actions to delete all my artifacts:

- https://github.com/Spendesk/purge-artifacts-action
- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/remove-artifacts

There is a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/161) as well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The guys on GitHub told me that I have to write the support and I did so.
The solution was that I had to set a spending limit. After setting my spending limit to 1$ everything works fine.

They told me that this is an **estimation** not the real data. I still think this a bug or at least pretty bad Usability but the solution worked for me.

After setting the spending limit GitHub told me that I am using 0,00GB of Storage so the delete actions actually worked. (I didn't have to pay anything)

Comment: but the only way to add a spending limit is by being on a paid plan already; FYI this was my other alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76859008/544947

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution:-

Click on Billing and Plans > Plans and Usage > Click on Update and add 1$ (1$ per month for extra storage).

Redeploy your project