# [GitHub Actions]: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that creates APKs for my Flutter app. This worked fine until recently, I seem to have exhausted some kind of quota. Now when the workflow runs I get this error:

```
Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts
```

**I assumed that deleting all artifacts would free up the space again** so I used another workflow to achieve this:

```
name: 'Delete old artifacts'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  delete-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: kolpav/purge-artifacts-action@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          expire-in: 0days
```

The new workflow seems to be working, I no longer see the old files in the GitHub UI. However, I still get the error when trying to run the APK workflow. Any ideas how to fix this error?

---

**Update**:

My GitHub says I have used up my included services (free version). Is there a way to undo that? Simply deleting the artifacts does not seem to be enough.
[image]

Comment: You can check under Settings -> Billing & plans. See under section: Storage for Actions and Packages.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Seems like I used up everything on accident  Is there a way for me to use of (free) GitHub actions again?

Comment: See also: [How to remove uploaded artifact? · Issue #5 · actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/5), [Error: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts · Issue #307 · actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/307) and [\[feat req\] Allow `retention-days` to be `0` · Issue #290 · actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/290).

Comment: I followed other's suggestions about removing old artifacts and decreasing the artifact retention time. After about 24 hours my usage did decrease from 0.75 to 0.59GB. This is still over the limit of 0.5GB. I added a payment method and set a $10/month quota, and my usage instantly decreased from 0.59GB to 0.22GB. So apparently adding a payment method and spending limit triggers a proper recount of usage. I'll leave the spending limit, but one might try removing it again and I would predict the usage would remain freed up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to undo. The quota is monthly, so you just have to wait for quota reset.

Github Actions (runner time) and Github Storage (artifacts) should have separate quotas.

For Github Actions, I know they are free for public repositories, so you could change your repository visibility, at least temporarily if you need it. As for Github Storage, I'm not sure if the same trick works, never tested.

Let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll just have to wait to till the end of the month and be more careful about storage next time.

Comment: Not sure on specific quotas, etc but switching to public visibility *did* allow me to run the pipeline in my case

Comment: This may have been true in the past, but it is definitely possible to delete artifacts to free up quota.  See @jakobinn's answer for details.

Comment: @SomeGuyontheInternet maybe GitHub changed something between your comment time and now. After my last deploy > 1 month ago, I ran into this issue. I've deleted every single artifact yet got this same error 2 min ago.

Answer (score 25):

You can actually delete old artifacts to bypass this. Just go to your actions, click on a previous build and check if there are stored artifacts at the bottom of the page. There is a recycle bin icon you can click to delete it.

[image: Artifact]

You can also specify when Github deletes old artifacts automatically for you. You go into Settings -> Actions -> General and find "Artifact and log retention".

[image: Artifact and log retention]

Note it might take some time for Github to update the completed quota.

See also [official docs](https://docs.github.com/organizations/managing-organization-settings/configuring-the-retention-period-for-github-actions-artifacts-and-logs-in-your-organization).

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: I have delete all artifacts manually but it's not working.

Answer (score 15):

2023 May.
**Repository-> Settings-> Actions-> General-> Artifact and log retention**

Set days to 1, that will delete the old automatic .and save it .

[image]

Comment: I tried but it's not working at all, even i have deleted old artifact manually on each deployment actions and wait for 24hrs but error remain as it is. do you have any other solution?

Comment: @JitendraSolanki Hello let me check that, did you find the solution ?

Comment: no, i didn't get any solution. Now i have added payment method and set limit to $1 and it's working fine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it simply takes care of the old artefacts all at once.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to stop this error by adding a new step on my deploy script:

```
  - name: Delete Old Artifacts
    uses: actions/github-script@v6
    id: artifact
    with:
      script: |
        const res = await github.rest.actions.listArtifactsForRepo({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
        })

        res.data.artifacts
          .forEach(({ id }) => {
            github.rest.actions.deleteArtifact({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              artifact_id: id,
            })
          })
```

Place it right above the upload step and it will delete all previous artifacts of the repo.

Comment: Hmm.. wonder if something changed. Seeing `RequestError [HttpError]: Resource not accessible by integration`. Maybe this needs tweaking for private repos?

Comment: I runned this step on a private repo and it worked. I need more context to understand your problem, but maybe this issue on GitHub helps you https://github.com/actions/first-interaction/issues/10

Comment: I add code by run manually https://github.com/aflopezbec/workflows/blob/main/.github/workflows/delete_artifacts_manually.yml

Comment: For private repo you would need to add `permissions: write-all`

Answer (score 4):

> I managed to stop this error by adding a new step on my deploy script:

To add the "Delete Old Artifacts" step, ensure you have selected the option "Read and write permissions" in Settings>Actions>General>Workflow permissions

Answer (score 3):

I've been so frustrated with this. We crafted a set of scripts that would:

- Delete release assets from all tags except the newer 2 tags of the repo.
- Delete all artifacts from all previous commits.

This workaround had been working for 1 or 2 months, until one day I decided to include 1 new artifact in my CI builds and releases. I thought: "it's only 30MB so I doubt it makes me go from (current) 0.3 GB consumption to surpass the allowed 0.5GB".

So I did it and... so far so good. But then suddenly 5 days later, I get:

- An email saying I've surpassed the quota.
- The "Billing and Plans" section of my github profile announcing my consumption is now 1.81 GB which DOESN'T MAKE ANY SENSE.
  If I click on the button "Get usage report", I just get a `.csv` file that just lists ***one single line*** where it tells me the repository name of the one consuming this, but it doesn't specify if it's artifacts, assets, or logs.

Now, before you criticize for not purchasing the paid option: I'm an indie dev that is not earning any revenue yet for my single-private-repo that is affected by this. All my other repos are opensource.

So then I decided to build the dirtiest hack of all but that works and eliminates all frustrations with this: a **script** that uploads the assets to a 2nd **git** repository just for binaries. I've managed to make it so that it pushes with `--force` to get rid of previous binaries (so that they don't live in the git history and it doesn't take ages/petabytes to download/store this).

If there's enough interest (just upvote this) I could opensource it, for example publish it in the GitHubActions marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with this issue a combination of the above answers worked for me today 11/16/2023

1. Adding script to delete old artifacts to the workflow file like @obertuccini posted (i put it prior to the build step so it first clears the aritfact storage)
2. Read and write permission in settings > Actions > General Workflow Permissions
3. Adding $1 (amount is prob not specific) to spending limit (for this you need to add card details, but IME you'll never get charged)

Note:
After adding money to the spending limit you wont be charged because you are now clearing the artifact storage everytime you build so no worries there :-)

Comment: but in order to have a spending limit you need to give your card details to GitHub, right?

Comment: yes, but it will never be charge added mine in Nov and it was never charged

Answer (score 1):

***November 2023*** Solution

How to solve it **FAST**?

1. Click on your profile image on top right corner in Github.com
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on **Billing and Plans** and later on Plans and usage
   [image]
4. Scroll down to **Storage for Actions and Packages**
   [image]
5. Click on **Update** and add **1$ (1$ per month for extra storage).**
6. Redeploy / Rebuild your project (on **Actions**).
7. **Done :)**

Comment: if someone got this error is because their storage is full. Adding $1 witout the step of clearing the storage will eventually cost you the $1 for the extra storage and you will have this issue again in no time.

Answer (score 0):

**2024**

Probably GitHub is not very intuitive with this issue. But we had the same problem running our Actions in our Orgazanitions repos.

In the Organization's settings page -> **Billing and plans**

[image]

Add a payment method and add a spending limit (We set it to $1.00 and Action jobs ran successfully)