# When deploying to Azure app service from GitHub I get "Artifact storage quota has been hit." error. How to I fix this?

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I try to deploy my Django app into Azure development using App Service with B1 plan.

It worked fine, but suddenly I can't deploy to Azure anymore.

When I read why the build failed I get this message:

```
Error: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts
```

My GitHub account is paid account and my repository is private.

This is my usage statistics on my GitHub account:
[image]

What can I do to get over that?

Should I upgrade my Azure plan or what?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference here to a quota link answered in another overflow forum:
[[GitHub Actions]: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730786/github-actions-create-artifact-container-failed-artifact-storage-quota-has-b)

***"There is no way to undo. The quota is monthly, so you just have to wait for quota reset.
Github Actions (runner time) and Github Storage (artifacts) should have separate quotas.
For Github Actions, I know they are free for public repositories, so you could change your repository visibility, at least temporarily if you need it. As for Github Storage, I'm not sure if the same trick works, never tested."***
 -frennky

TLDR-check billing and plans in your github actions

Comment: Yes I read that. So the limitation is coming from GithHub? Then I should find another way to deploy to Azure?

Comment: I think for continuous integration there is a few options but both github actions and azure devops have artifact storage limits. Just to confirm, is this github actions you are using for continuous integration?

Comment: It uses this: ´Run actions/checkout@v2´

Comment: You can honestly try deleting old or unused artifacts to make space, i'd recommend this if you are using continuous integration. I'm not sure of the size of the current artifact you are trying to upload.
You can delete them using this doc:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#downloading-or-deleting-artifacts